# ASP.NET C# - get image from QueryString and save it to server as .ico

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ico

I'm newbie in asp.net so I need some help how to solve this.

Basically idea is:

1. get image from QueryString, for example: /Default.aspx?src=http://www.google.hr/images/logo.png
2. convert it and resize to 16x16 px ".ico" IE compilant
3. save it to server, and print/echo URL to ico

Using ASP.NET 3.5 C#
This is my try:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var source = Request.QueryString["src"];

            if (source != null)
            {

                WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
                using (Stream stream = webclient.OpenRead(source))
                {
                    Bitmap iconbitmap = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(webclient));
                    var icon = Icon.FromHandle((iconbitmap).GetHicon());
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream("/test1.ico", FileMode.Create);
                    icon.Save(fs);
                    fs.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Got some errors 
(Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(string)' has some invalid arguments )

Thanks

Comment: What problem would you like help with?

Comment: I've edited... I get some errors with posted code. And I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        using (Stream stream = webclient.OpenRead(source))
        {
            Bitmap iconbitmap = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream));
            var icon = Icon.FromHandle((iconbitmap).GetHicon());
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("/test1.ico", FileMode.Create);
            icon.Save(fs);
            fs.Close();
        }
```

or if you don't need conversion:

```
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.DownloadFile(source, "/test1.ico");
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.Drawing.Image.FromFile()` is expecting a string, you are passing it a `WebClient`.

Comment: Thanks for replay... As I said, I'm ASP newbie, this is my first app. Samich solution worked good.